# How to merge 2 jsp pages

Tags: jsp

I have two jsp pages. result.jsp, x.jsp. x.jsp is a menu view page which has some links through which we can filter our result.jsp. I want to merge these 2 pages. how to do it?

Comment: merge means? (1) Do you want to have the content of both of them in a single jsp OR (2) Do you want that they remain separate jsp but when they are rendered on the browser they should be rendered as a single page? which one is it or is it something else?

Comment: right now i have two separate working jsps. so wen i hit search they both gotta be rendered on single page

Answer (score 3):

You can either use

1. static include `<%@include file="x.jsp" %>` (included at compile time)
2. or dynamic include `<jsp:include page="x.jsp" />` (included while rendering the output)

inside your `results.jsp` or the other way round i.e. including `results.jsp` in `x.jsp`.

For more info:

1. [Include another JSP file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110412/468763)
2. [Difference between the two includes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7879906/468763)
3. `<%@include %>` is a [directive](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_directives.htm) and `<js:include />` is a [standard-action](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_actions.htm).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u very much praksah. i tried then already but non of them are working for me. it just blanks off the page with just header n footer

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Any stack-trace? or does the jsp page actually gets called, have you checked?