# header file reload again and again in jsp

Tags: css, jsp, jakarta-ee, header-files

My All Js and css are in script.jsp file and include on every page

```
<jsp:include page="../include/scripts.jsp" />
```

when page submit / refresh it reload again and again ?

How to control this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation I found that could explain it. It helped me out when i needed it

Here's an explanation of the problem...

Clicking the "submit" button on a form sends a request to the web server, which includes all the data entered on the form. Not only the URL but also the form data is part of the request, and this request is remembered by the browser. If the user clicks "refresh", the browser repeats the request, sending the same URL and form data to the web server again.

But forms can be submitted in two different ways, GET or POST, depending on the "method" attribute of the "form" tag. There is a convention that a GET request has no side-effects; it only fetches data but does not make any changes to the database. On the other hand, if a request changes data it should always use a POST request. As I said, these are only conventions, and there is not much technical difference between them, but a very important difference is that browsers will warn the user if they try to repeat a POST -- clicking "refresh" will pop up a dialog box warning the user that this may cause an operation to be repeated, and confirming that they really want to resubmit. The browser does not show this confirmation when refreshing a GET request.

Is your form using the GET method changing it to POST is the simplest solution, since this will at least mean that the user is warned if they try to refresh.

But a better solution is the POST+REDIRECT+GET idiom suggested by @cletus. This splits the database update (POST) and the view (GET) into two operations. Clicking refresh on the browser then merely repeats the GET, which has no side-effects.

Comment: @StackOverflow really? you really got it? This answer does nothing for your problem IMO

Answer (score 0):

Use the include directive `<%@ include/>` as against the `<jsp:include/>` tag you're using now.

`<jsp:include/>` will instruct the jsp runtime to go and fetch the included resource everytime the compiler comes across that tag (first-time requests, refreshes) while `<@ include/>` means that the included resource is built into the parent resource at compile-time

The difference is that the directive is a compile-time include. This means that the content of the directive (in your case *scripts.jsp*) is baked into the parent jsp (and ultimately the servlet that the jsp will be compiled into). The effect is that the included file is read only the first time the parent jsp is rendered.

What you should have:

```
    <%@ include page="../include/scripts.jsp" />
```

Related:

- [What is the difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file)