# How to create HTML Templates

Tags: html, templates, include

I have several HTML pages and some of the content is same for all the pages. Is there a way to put the content into a single file and include it in all the HTML Pages?

Lets say that the common data is in HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `iframes` for this purpose.

Design your master page in .html format and use it with `iframe` tag

```
 <iframe src="MasterPage.html"></iframe>
```

Refer following link:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/iframe

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a [templating solution](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jsp as follows

by using two ways

```
<jsp:include page="reuse.html" />
```

or

```
<@include file="reuse.html">
```

Have a look at this question  [What is the difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three places:

1. **At build/publication time** — you generate HTML documents from your data sources and then publish static files. This option works for everybody, but can make the build times rather long for very large sites. I use [ttree](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) for this.
2. **At run time, on the server** — this works in much the same way as the previous option, but is done on the server and on demand (i.e. when a page is requested). [Template-toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tutorial/Web.html#section_Dynamic_Content_Generation_Via_CGI_Script) is also an option here, but here are many many others, including [Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/) and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).
3. **At run time, on the client** — this involves pulling the content together using frames or JavaScript. It is unfriendly to search engines and will break bookmarking unless you are very careful. I don't recomment it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using PHP.

for example if all pages have a common header, create a new document with the name of header.php and place the contents of the header div inside. Every other page you want the  header to appear just call it by using :

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is at **run time**.

This means using PHP, ASP, JSP or another server-side scripting solution to join your pages together on demand when sending them to the client.

In PHP, this can be achieved with the following:

```
<?php
    include_once("head.php");
?>
<!-- some body content -->
<?php
    include_once("foot.php");
?>
```

Managing your header, footer and content all separately makes it very easy to update your design without having to edit many files.

It is **not** recommended to do this client-side with frames/iframes, as this is very unfriendly to search engines and can slow down your server as several HTTP requests must be initiated.