# create java function in a jsp file and call it from another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

We generally create methods in a java class, import them into a jsp file and call those methods in our jsp files.

But we are working in a client environment, we do not have access to create or modify .java files. So we desperately need to create a function in a jsp file and call it from another jsp file.

For example:

A.jsp

```
.....
<jsp:include page="B.jsp"/>
....
<%= getName(); %>
```

B.jsp ....

```
<%!
public String getName()
{
 return "Hello";
}
>%
```

Is there  any way to do this?.

Comment: Can you use tag files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, instead of

```
<jsp:include page="B.jsp"/>
```

Use

```
<%@include file="B.jsp"%>
```

Including page will just embed two jsp code so you are not getting that function but including file using directives will embed code first and then compile so you will get your function.

You can find difference here

[What is the difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file)

Comment: This worked out for me.  Even though it is not a good practice to do this, this will useful till we get access to java files. Thank you!

Comment: @Prathap You can accept answer if it solves your problem by clicking on right symbol top left corner.

Comment: Done!. Marked as this is useful for me.

Answer (score 6):

You should not create a function in `Jsp` file. JSP's are meant for view purpose only .

You can write the function in separate `java class` and call that class from whatever `Jsp` pages you want.

Comment: It would be useful for future users if you mention the reason also

Comment: Reason is that they cannot communicate between without a request object.

Comment: @javaBeginner *"JSP's are meant for view purpose only"* is the reason.

Comment: @Uooo If so then why java provides scripletts?

Comment: Good answer, but doesnt match the question! Prathap said that he just can't do this!

Comment: @javaBeginner Since these comments do not add any value to the post, I would suggest doing a simple Stackoverflow or Google search to find out why it is recommended not to use scriptlets nowadays. Scriptlets still exist because they were the only possibility to control the flow of a JSP before taglibs.

Comment: @Uooo I was asking because if a user later views this question then it will be useful for them

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i have some restrictions to write java files.

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are all valid. Do not do this. Its a bad design. But, if you just what to know any possible way of doing this, it can be using static includes of the JSP.

You can use <%@include %> directive to include JSP fragments

```
<%@include file="B.jsp" %>
```

in A.jsp

The good design would be for you to create a Class in java and write all your methods in it, include it in all ur JSPs, and use the methods.

Other people are confused with similar questions, like how to call a JS function in one JSP/HTML to another JSP/HTML, the answer remains same. The good design would be to use a .js file to write all JS Methods.

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are all valid. However, if you must do this, I would improve it a bit by putting all functions in a separate file and call it `methods.inc` and then include it in jsp file like

`<%@include file="methods.inc" %>`

This will help you to know the intention clearly and look somewhat cleaner too.