# JSP include other jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

for example i made three `jsp` file like this

```
example1.jsp

<%
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    map.put(test1);
    map.put(test2);
    %>
```

-

```
example2.jsp
<%
        out.print(map.get(test1));
    %>
```

-

```
example3.jsp
<%
        out.print(map.get(test2));
    %>
```

i want to using variable map declaration at `example1.jsp` and

using at `exmple2.jsp` and `exmaple3.jsp`

how can i using variable like this?

Comment: `<jsp:include page="..." />` You can use this and include any jsp page with another.

Comment: @Ashish oh... i use example4.jsp include example2.jsp and example4.jsp this make error duplicate field map :( is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you considered session attributes to "share" data between pages, if that is what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<%@include file="example2.jsp" %>` and `<%@include file="example3.jsp" %>` in your first jsp. Basically what you are doing is you are statically including the two jsp files. The variables declared in first jsp will be visible in second and third jsp.

If you do a jsp include then the variables define in first jsp will not be visible in second and third jsp due to the fact that it is a dynamic include

See this more details
[What is the difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file)

Comment: thanks diffrence difference between <jsp:include page = ... > and <%@ include file = ... >? is really helpful for my problem !