# struts2 custom 400 error page not working

Tags: java, http, web, servlets, struts2

**response.java**

```
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
response.setStatus(400);
return json;
```

**struts.xml**

```
<package name="callresponse" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="response" method="response" class="response.action">
        <result name="json">/WEB-JSP/json.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-JSP/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**error.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
Custom Error Page!!!!
```

can see the error page on localhost. But when I put it on the server and call the domain, it only sends BadRequest.
The server was configured with IIS + Tomcat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001380/573032

Comment: i want to return http status 400 and message.
i don't want to return http status 302.

Comment: Can you show where http status 302 is returned?